# Flutter: Different Keyboard for TextField having Pattern

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a TextField which accepts a input with specific pattern.

**Pattern - [A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}**

- Pattern accepts - First 5 characters as any Alphabets.
- Then Any 4 numbers
- Then Any 1 Alphabet

Example - **ABCD1234E**

---

**I wan't following behavior to happen !**

> Alphabet Keyboard should pop for first 5 Alphabets.
>
> Then a Numeric Keyboard should pop for next 4 numbers.
>
> & Then Alphabet Keyboard for last character.

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible, and probably isn't a good behavior; having the keyboard swap on you while typing would be very annoying for a user. If you want to restrict the field to a certain pattern you can implement [TextInputFormatter](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/TextInputFormatter-class.html)

Comment: Actually I've seen it in one app ! So I was wondering how it can be done. !

Comment: It may done if you do 3 TextFields as one TextField, if you still interesting I can make an answer for you.